# 'Password-Confirm Password' error

Tags: php, mysql, post, passwords

I have here my code. I just want to add the confirm password textfield on my website. However if i'm putting the `if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']){
   $message = "Your passwords did not match.";
}`. It just showing the passwords did not match but still, it is going to my database. What I want is if the password and confirm password textfield did not match, a dialog box will appear telling the error. AND it will not be put in the database unless complete and correct.

Here is my php code.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];


    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $studnoquery=mysql_query("");





    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

    $passconfirm=($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']);

    if($numrows==0)

    {


    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
            (full_name, email, username,password) 
            VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
     $message = "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
     $message = "Failed to insert data information!";
    }
    } 

    //if numrows is greater than 1
    else {
     $message = "That username already exists! Please try another one!";
    }
} 


else {
     $message = "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>
```

I think the `if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password'])` is correct but i'm having a hard time where to put it on my code. Thanks. Help me.

Comment: You never use `$passconfirm`. In fact, the only error checking you do is to check to see if the username exists. You're also using an obsolete API and are wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: Your code shows as `$passconfirm=($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']);` and not `if($_POST['password']...` so it will always evaluate to false.

Comment: I know that. But i'm still working on it. What I'm trying to ask is where to place the `if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password'])` code. Wherever I'm putting it, Altough it says "Passwords did not match" still it is inserting into my database. Please help. Feel free to edit my code.

Comment: Place `if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']){ $message = "Your passwords did not match."; exit; }` right after `$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];` - Plus, why the empty `""` in `$studnoquery=mysql_query("");`? There should be a variable in there. `$studnoquery=mysql_query($query);`

Comment: You're also storing passwords in plain text. If this is to be a LIVE site, you **will** get hacked. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Plus,  [**use prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code just replace it. Placed `$error` variable. If password and confirm password didn't match then `$error` variable's value will be 1 otherwise it will be null.

```
  <?php

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];


    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $studnoquery=mysql_query("");





    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    $error = '';
    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']) { 
            $message = "Your passwords did not match."; 
            $error = 1;
    }
    $passconfirm=($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']);

    if($numrows==0 && $error=='')

    {


    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
            (full_name, email, username,password) 
            VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
     $message = "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
     $message = "Failed to insert data information!";
    }
    } 

    //if numrows is greater than 1
    else {
     $message = "That username already exists! Please try another one!";
    }
} 


else {
     $message = "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't just regurgitate OP's code without explaining WHAT you've changed.

Comment: #Marc i explained the additional code as per your comments.

Comment: Now. It always falls under the "That username already exists! Please try another one!";. And still confirm password is not showing.

Comment: @kerv: so check your db and see if that account exists already.